# Насколько актуальна сейчас спецификация nothrow в С++?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

Когда-то давно в С++ была возможность указать для метода/функции спецификацию nothrow. Которая указывала, что метод/функция не выбрасывает исключений.

Как дисциплинированный пользователь, я попробовал я в свое время использовать эту спецификацию. Но вскоре выяснилось, что при разработке очень утомительно отслеживать, какие функции выбрасывают исключение, а какие нет. И я перестал указывать nothrow.

Сейчас появился проект, в котором принципиально нет генерации исключений. В связи с этим появились вопросы.

Вопросы:

1. Поддерживается ли сейчас в стандарте спецификация nothrow?
2. Рекомендована ли сейчас в стандарте спецификация nothrow? Или, как часто бывает с С++ с нововведениями, она объявлена устаревшей.
3. Что дает использование спецификации nothrow? Может ли транслятор генерировать более быстрый/компактный код при использовании спецификации nothrow? Или никакой разницы нет?
4. Можно ли сразу указать транслятору, что все методы класса имеют спецификацию nothrow? Чтобы не возиться с каждым методом и не указывать в нем nothrow.

Comment: Вы явно путаете спецификатор `__declspec(nothrow)` или `std::nothrow`. Спецификатора `nothrow` в С++ никогда не было. Средств контроля над исключениями во время компиляции язык до сих под не предлагает, а даже те, что были (но никогда не работали), были исключены из языка (имеется ввиду спецификаторы исключений типа `throw(…)`). Добавленный спецификатор `noexcept` таким средством тоже не является (и вообще его название вводит в заблуждение).

Comment: *"как часто бывает с С++ с нововведениями, она объявлена устаревшей"* - скорее наоборот, гораздо чаще бывает упорное нежелание избавляться от устаревших и откровенно вредных фич языка. Ломать обратную совместимость мало кто решится.

Comment: "Может ли транслятор генерировать более быстрый/компактный код" Если компилятору не мешать тонной ненужных слов и уточнений, то компилятор как раз может сделать очень хороший код. А если уточнений появляется слишком много, то компилятор скажет "ок, ССЗБ" и отключит большинство оптимизаций.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Вероятно, что Вы говорит о `throw()`, т.к. `std::nothrow` это немного другое. Спецификация `throw()` помечена как устаревшая (deprecated) в C++17 и будет удалена из будущих стандартов, поэтому использовать её не рекомендуется. В современном стандарте есть другой спецификатор: `noexcept`, суть которого в том, чтобы вызывать `std::terminate` если исключение покидает функцию, помеченную этим спецификатором.

С использованием `noexcept` код *может* получиться лучше, но основная задача этого спецификатора задавать соответствующие интерфейсы. Поэтому нет никаких механизмов, которые делают всё `noexcept` — каждый интерфейс должен быть явно помечен (за исключением деструкторов, которые являются `noexcept` по умолчанию).

Comment: Значение и полезность noexcept существенно шире, чем просто вызов `std::terminate`. Теперь она стала частью типа функции. Например, реализация `std::vector` будет *перемещать* элементы при переаллокации памяти вектора только если конструктор перемещения является noexcept.

Comment: @AnT, несомненно, это часть интерфейса. Я об этом написал, но раскрывать не стал. Каждый решает сам, какую пользу можно получить от такого интерфейса (я знаю, что то, что Вы описали и было причиной появления noexcept). Про суть `noexcept` я написал для того, чтобы подчеркнуть, то, чем этот спецификатор не является — аналогом throws из Java

Answer (score 4):

Немного о константе `std::nothrow_t  nothrow` и  спецификаторе  `noexcept`

Известно что: Когда `operator new`  не может выделить память, генерирует исключение `std::bad_alloc`. Для демонстрации  напишем функцию:

```
template < class T >
void capture1(T** p) throw(std::bad_alloc)
{       
    int i{};
    while (true) {
        try {
            *p++ = new T[100000]; // когда нибудь в память будет исчерпана
            ++i;
        }        
        catch (std::bad_alloc& exc) {
            std::cout << "На шаге "  
                      << i << "  генерирован  " << exc.what() << std::endl;
            return;
        }
    }    
}
```

Но может быть нам понадобится написать такую же функцию, не генерирующую исключение. И часто, для пользователей удобно знать, что эта функция не генерирует  никакого исключения (мы об этом явно можем сказать в обьявлении функции).

```
template < class T >
void capture2(T** p) noexcept
{        
    int i{};
    while (true) {
        // Если оператор не найдет память, то указатель просто станет нулевым
        *p++ = new(std::nothrow) T[100000]; // когда нибудь в память будет исчерпана
        ++i;
        if (*p == 0)  {
            std::cout << "Память исчерпана на шаге " << i   << std::endl ;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

И в нашей программе:

```
    //...
    int** pi = new int*[100000];
    capture1(pi); // на шаге  i  сгенерировано исключение std::bad_alloc
    capture2(pi); //  память исчерпанa на шаге i 
    // дальше освобождения памяти и  все другое
```

Это всего лишь демонстрация того, что и как...